# Getting wrong message for function

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with running my function. The program is supposed to see if a group of 3 numbers is valid or not only if it is between 200 and 800. Even thought the value such as -5 is invalid, the results still say its valid. Can somebody help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are running into Undefined Behavior because you are not initializing your bool variables.

```
bool ansa, ansb, ansc, overall;
```

In C and C++ an expression is considered "false" when it evaluates to 0, otherwise it is considered true.

```
if (!0)
    std::cout << "!0 is true" << std::endl;
if (3)
    std::cout << "3 is true" << std::endl;
if (255)
    std::cout << "255 is true" << std::endl;
```

What is happening is that the program is assigning space for `ansa`, `ansb` and `ansc` on the stack. If those locations happen to have been used already by your program in a previous function call, they may have non-zero values that cause them to evaluate to 'true'.

You need to set these to be false by default:

```
bool ansa = false, ansb = false, ansc = false, overall = false;
```

or you need to assign them values of "false" when you find that their conditions are not met (the 'else' cases of your tests):

```
bool isitavalidgroup (int a, int b, int c)
{
    bool ansa, ansb, ansc, overall;

    if ((a <= 800) && (a >= 200)){
        ansa = true;
    }
    else {
        cout << a << " is invalid" << endl;
        ansa = false;
    }
    if ((b <= 800) && (b >= 200)) {
        ansb = true;
    }
    else {
        cout << b << " is invalid" << endl;
        ansb = false;
    }
    if ((c <= 800) && (c >= 200))  {
        ansc = true;
    }
    else {
        cout << c << " is invalid" << endl;
        ansc = false;
    }
    if (ansa && ansb && ansc == true){
        overall = true;
    }
    else {
        overall = false;
    }
    return overall;
}
```

Also, you could rewrite your code to use "short circuit" logic - that is, for the group to be valid all three variables must be valid. If any one is invalid, you immediately know that the group is no-longer valid. So return false when you find your first error condition rather than proceeding to test all of them.

```
if (a && b && c)
```

The "&&" means "AND ALSO", so if `a` is false, the condition cannot be true, so there is no reason to go on and figure out if `b` and `c` are also true.

```
bool isItAValidGroup(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (a < 200 || a > 800) {
        cout << a << " is invalid" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (b < 200 || b > 800) {
        cout << b << " is invalid" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (c < 200 || c > 800) {
        cout << c << " is invalid" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // everything passed.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized ansa, ansb, or ansc.  You explicitly set them to true in your conditional statements, but you never set them to false.  Therefore, their values are not defined and will be considered true as long as they don't happen to be initialized as a zero.